# mysql show offset with query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have some data in my database

```
---------
| Name  | Offset(only for imagine it)
---------
| Aa    | 1
| Ab    | 2
| Ba    | 3
| Cf    | 4
| As    | 5
---------
```

when use this query

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1,3;
```

it must be show 3 of the first data, Aa, Ab, Ba, with offset like that.
Now, I want to selecting all of Name with prefix a, so use this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 1,3;
```

I want to show the result of that query with the offset, how to do this?
Loop it is not the solution I needed.

```
---------
| Name  | Offset(only for imagine it)
---------
| Aa    | 1
| Ab    | 2
| As    | 5
---------
```

Any help appreciated
Thank you!

Comment: MySQL, unlike SQL Server, does not have any built in row number function.  That being said, if you plan on using the row number, why not add a column for it instead of leaving it as imaginary?

Comment: if the database content manipulated, imaginary number should change too, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You have it mostly correct. However, rows start at 0. So the answer: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 0,3

That SQL query will select everything in the table *table* that starts with the letter 'a' (or 'A').

For alphabetical order, use ORDER BY Name.